# Draw string object with UIFont in custom UIPrintPageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, airprint, uiprintpagerenderer

I'm subclassing UIPrintPageRenderer to draw my own page for printing via AirPrint. I have a simple String object that I'd like to change the size of the font. Using the drawAtPoint withAttributes method, it string is drawn in the correct location, but the font name and size is unchanged. Is it possible to use NSAttributedStrings within the drawPageAtIndex method of UIPrintPageRenderer?

Sample code:

```
import UIKit

class MyPrintPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {
    override func drawPageAtIndex(pageIndex: Int, inRect printableRect: CGRect) {
        let font = UIFont(name: "Times", size: 72.0)!
        var stringAttributes = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
        stringAttributes["NSFontAttributeName"] = font

        let lineOne = "Some text"
        let lineOnePointX = CGRectGetMidX(printableRect) - nameLineOne.sizeWithAttributes(stringAttributes).width / 2
        let lineOnePointY = CGRectGetMinY(printableRect)
        let lineOnePoint = CGPoint(x: lineOnePointX, y: lineOnePointY)
        lineOne.drawAtPoint(lineOnePoint, withAttributes: stringAttributes)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using NSFontAttributeName as a String in the key of stringAttributes rather than the type itself. Removing the quotes fixed the issue.